# Год в предложении. Что это за синтаксическая конструкция?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> (1) 1980 год - совершено открытие рентгеновских лучей.
>
> (2) 2005 год - массовые беспорядки во Франции.

Какие это синтаксические конструкции? Год - это номинативное предложение в составе сложного предложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне не встречался анализ подобных конструкций в источниках, поэтому могу предложить только **своё понимание темы.**

1) Соответствие года и события может оформляться в виде **хронологических таблиц,** причем оформление к жестким правилам не привязано и имеет варианты, связанные с наличие тире, точки, прописной буквы и т.д.

https://histerl.ru/xronologicheskaia-tablica

https://novainfo.ru/book/4

2) Другое дело, если **запись вставлена в текст,** тогда конструкцию следует считать предложением и можно определить ее вид.

Например: ***2005 год – массовые беспорядки во Франции.***

Предложение **двусоставное эллиптическое,**  включает обстоятельство времени и подлежащее. Сравнить: *Тихо в комнате просторной, а за окнами – мороз. Снова в час ночной тучи над землёй. Посреди небесных тел лик луны туманный.*

Но вот только в качестве обстоятельства использует **номинатив**. Его нельзя считать ни номинативным предложением, ни изолированным номинативом. **Это просто номинатив (И.п.) в функции обстоятельства.**

Сравнить: ***В 2005 году – массовые беспорядки во Франции.***

Такие предложения требуют определенного **контекста**, когда высказывается какое-либо суждение и потом подтверждается рядом фактов.

Comment: Используемая запись в [Википедии](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавная_страница) - это скорее хронологическая таблица?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, это именительный темы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылки на источники или другие доводы, подтверждающие Ваше мнение