# Время в предложении

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> 9 часов — комиссия приступает к подсчету голосов.
>   13 часов — небольшой перерыв.
>   16 часов — получены первые результаты.
>   20 часов — опубликование результатов на сайте.

Какой синтаксической конструкцией является время события?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, номинативные предложения - точное указание времени. Здесь же есть бытийное значение, значит, номинатив.

Хотя можно охарактеризовать и как неполное с пропуском сказуемого: (Исполнилось)9 часов.(Пробило 13 часов). И т.д. Смотря как к этому подойти.

Но я бы ответила - номинативное.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я задавал подобный вопрос, и я склоняюсь к ответу [Sharon](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444640/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/448844#448844).

Answer (score 0):

Если бы было:

> 9.00 — комиссия приступает к подсчету голосов.
>   13.00 — небольшой перерыв.
>   16.00 — получены первые результаты.
>   20.00 — опубликование результатов на сайте.

то может и вопросов не было. 
В исходном вопросе непонятно: речь о пройденных 9 часах (прошло девять часов) или о 9 часах утра (о часах времени суток)?